# if $z=x+iy=re^{i\theta}$ and $f(z) = u+iv = \rho e^{i\phi},$ how can we represent f in the following ways

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> if $z=x+iy=re^{i\theta}$ and $\omega :=f(z) = u+iv = \rho e^{i\phi},$
>   How can we represent f with
>
> (a) $u$ and $v$ as functions of $x,y$;
>
> (b) $u$ and $v$ as functions of $r,\theta$;
>
> (c) $\rho$ and $\phi$ as functions of $x,y$
>
> (d) $\rho$ and $\phi$ as functions of $r,\theta$

In each of the cases, assuming the differentiability, I have to write down the neccessary conditions in order for $f$ to be holomorphic.

I am allowed to assume $z\ne0$ and/or $\omega \ne 0$ if neccessary.

Now for part (a) , I wrote $f(z) = f(x+iy) = Re(x+iy) + iImf(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

If the functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and have continuous partial derivatives in an open set $U$, then the function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $z=x+iy$, is analytic in $U$.

and for part (b) I wrote $f(z) = u(r,\theta) + iv(r,\theta) $ and I wrote this:
[image: cre]

Now I do not know parts (c) and (d), I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just some chain rules. For example $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$

Comment: HINT: if $f(z)\in\Bbb C$ then $f(z)=|f(z)|e^{i\arg(f(z))}$